# How to hide sidebar and stop div container from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, overflow, sidebar

I have an image and a sidebar.

```html
<div id="outer" style="max-width:1020px;min-width:730px;overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">

  <div id="image" style="float:left;max-width:720px;">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="max-width:720px;" />
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar" style="width:300px;float:right;">
    content
  </div>

</div>
```

I would like the sidebar to disappear if the window is resized and there is not enough space to show the sidebar.

Unfortunately, the sidebar drops to the bottom and wraps when the window is resized.

I have tried `white-space: nowrap;`, but that does not seem to apply here.
The image container can have various heights, so I cannot set it to a fixed height.

How can I stop the "outer" `div` from expanding and make the sidebar drop out of view when the window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

to be honest you should use a responsive grid to achieve this, bootstrap by Twitter has a very clear way of implementing the desired behaviour you are looking for, but there's lots out there..

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

Answer (score 0):

u could use,

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if(document.body.cilentwidth < 1020) 
      document.getElementById('sidebar').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    else
       document.getElementById('sidebar').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

the resize event in javascript, check existing windows' width and according to it, then hide/show the div using `document.getElementById('sidebar').style.visibility = 'hidden/visible'` according to your requirement.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion. The sidebar is hidden. But whenever I resize the window, there still is an empty where the sidebar used to show. I've already tried the visibility=collapse, but it has the same effect.

Comment: use `document.body.cilentwidth` for width comparision. look i've **edited** my answer.